# Problems linking glew and glut with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project on windows that I am trying to build on Windows using Cmake (Mingw). I need to link glew and glut libraries with my project. This is my CMakeLists.txt file at the top project level.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.1)
project(Pacman)

# message("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Glew/include/glew.h")

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glew-2.2.0")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glew-2.2.0/lib/Release/Win32/")
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/freeglut")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/freeglut/lib")
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)

find_path(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR gl/glew.h)
find_library(GLEW_LIBRARIES NAMES GLEW glew32 glew glew32s)

message(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
message(${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(${GLUT_LIBRARY})

include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR})

find_path(GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR GL/glut.h)
find_library(GLUT_LIBRARIES NAMES GLUT freeglut PATH_SUFFIXES lib64)

file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")

message(${SOURCES})

add_executable(game ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(game GLEW::GLEW GLUT::GLUT)
```

I used the following glew library and placed it inside my folder directory so I can link it with my own project.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/2.1.0/

I used the following freeglut MSVC library and placed it inside my folder directory so I can link it with my project.
https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/files/software/development/GLUT/freeglut-MSVC.zip

This is my overall folder structure

-> Pacman (this is the parent folder)

--> build

--> freeglut

--> glew-2.2.0

--> other cpp and h files

--> CMakeLists.txt

When I run **cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..** in build folder I get the following output meaning that the libraries were found and linked.

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found GLEW: D:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/glew-2.2.0/include (found version "2.2.0") 
-- Found PkgConfig: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/pkg-config.exe (found version "1.8.0") 
-- Checking for module 'glut'
--   Package 'glut', required by 'virtual:world', not found
-- Found GLUT: D:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/freeglut/lib/freeglut.lib  
D:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/glew-2.2.0/include
D:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/glew-2.2.0/lib/Release/x64/glew32.lib
D:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/freeglut/include
D:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/freeglut/lib/freeglut.lib
D:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/Board.cppD:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/Bomb.cppD:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/Bomberman.cppD:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/Character.cppD:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/Ghosts.cppD:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/Point.cppD:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/bomber_Pacman.cppD:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/util.cpp
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Daniyal/Semester 2/Pacman/build
```

When I try to **make** the project in the build folder, it gives multiple errors. I am going to copy-paste some of them below.

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\game.dir/objects.a(util.cpp.obj):util.cpp:(.text+0x17b4): undefined reference to `glVertex4f'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\game.dir/objects.a(util.cpp.obj):util.cpp:(.text+0x17f6): undefined reference to `glVertex4f'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\game.dir/objects.a(util.cpp.obj):util.cpp:(.text+0x1824): undefined reference to `glVertex4f'
```

Can someone guide me? Is there something I am doing wrong while linking (keeping in mind that I am a beginner in cmake).

Comment: `glVertex4f` is part OpenGL. You need to link with `GL` library.

Comment: The call `find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)` sets `GLEW_LIBRARIES` and `GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS` variables. Why do you set these variables again (with `find_library` and `find_path`)?